# chaco plot range dynamic update

Tags: python, python-2.7, plot, enthought, chaco

I have a series of chaco plots that are dynamically updated with a timer object. I would like to set the Y (*"value"* in chaco speak) limits when the data changes.

When I initialise the plot object I call

```
obj.alldata = ArrayPlotData(frequency=frequencies)
# Cycle through the channels and add a set to the alldata object    
for [i,v] in enumerate(channels):
    setname="amplitude{:d}".format(v)
    obj.alldata.set_data(setname, empty_amplitude)

for c in config['plots']:
    thisplot=Plot(obj.alldata)
    xlim=thisplot.index_mapper.range
    xlim.low=1
    xlim.high=1000
    ylim=thisplot.value_mapper.range
    ylim.low=0.001
    ylim.high=1000

thisplot.plot(("frequency", initdata),
                 name="Spec",
                 value_scale="log",
                 index_scale="log")

container.add(thisplot)
```

Then, later I update the data array with:

```
def onTimer(self, *args):
    '''This is fired every time the timer is triggered 
    '''
      # Get the data 


    for [i,v] in enumerate(self.channels):
        data=getsimdata(self.s,v,int(self.config['numsamp']))
        self.alldata.set_data(setname,data)
```

This all work fine except I would like to auto range the plot afdter the data has been added.  I have seen various pages suggest `DataRange2D` and `value_mapper` but I have no idea how to use them. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think that if you remove the statements `ylim.low = 0.001` and `ylim.high = 100` it will autorange. I've not been able to set initial limits than can be automatically changed.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that and it works ok for a linear scale but not for loglog scale.

Answer (score 1):

for auto ranging:

thisPlot.range2d.y_range.high = 'auto'

for specific range:

thisPlot.range2d.y_range.high = 1000

thisPlot.range2d.y_range.low = .001

you can switch between the two by creating a Bool trait "enableAutoRange."  on trait change, you can set the plot values as stated above.